# Cookie with claims not being set on "production" server

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I'm using IdentityServer3 along a webforms app, I was able to replicate the id_token retrieval on my local machine following the [MVC No Library Client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcFormPostClient). My full source is posted on GitHub as [IdServer3-WebFormsAppDemo](https://github.com/chouzar/IdentityServer3-WebFormsAppDemo).

However, when moving to the actual production server it seems that the app is unable to set the claims. This is the callback that handles the cookie sign in (just after the user authenticates and gives consent):

```
// AuthorizationCallback.aspx
private async Task ProcessRequest () {
    var idToken = Request.Form["id_token"];
    var state = Request.Form["state"];

    if (idToken == null) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid id_token");
    }

    var claims = await ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(idToken, state);
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", idToken));
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(claimsIdentity);

    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

After token validation and cookie sign in, the app redirects to another form and displays the id_token claims:

```
// Default.aspx
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    heading.InnerText = Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? "User Is Authenticated" : "User Is Not Authenticated";
    foreach (var claim in Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims) {
    AddListElement(claim.Type, claim.Value);
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the token is being validated successfully on **AuthorizationCallback.aspx** and the claims are being obtained, when redirecting to **Default.aspx** claims are being displayed when testing locally but no when testing from the production server.

**Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** always results on false, and there are no stored claims the **User** object. When inspecting from my browser I can see these 2 cookies on the Response Headers:

```
set-cookie:.AspNet.TempCookie=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
set-cookie:.AspNet.ApplicationCookie=fyMP9H ... Gt-7VlTA; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

But only when testing the app from *localhost*, in the production server these cookies are not present. What could be causing this behaviour? Any help or clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I just discovered what was causing the issue. My **AuthorizationCallback.aspx** form was configured so it could process async methods:

```
// AuthorizationCallback.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Needed in order to process ValidateIdentityTokenAsync below
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ProcessRequest));
}

private async Task ProcessRequest () {
    var idToken = Request.Form["id_token"];
    ...
    var claims = await ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(idToken, state);
    ...
}
```

By modifying the form so it doesn't process async requests I was able to get the claims working for me:

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var idToken = Request.Form["id_token"];
    ...
    var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        await ValidateIdentityTokenAsync(idToken, state)
    );
    var claims = task.Result;
    ....
}
```

I'm still unsure why this change solved my issue, but I'm guessing it had to do with the async methods exiting before SignIn? Now that I have a blocking routine the issue is no more.